# PHP array string key add number at the end

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

Good day fellas!

I have this block of code where i create a JSON string and i have a dynamic number of data so what i need is also a dynamic name for a key..

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["members"] = array();
    $x = 0;
    $members = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $members = array();
        $members["member" + (string)$x] = array();
        $member["member_id"] = $row["member_id"];
        $member["firstname"] = $row["firstname"];
        $member["mi"] = $row["mi"];
        $member["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];
        $member["email"] = $row["email"];
        $member["username"] = $row["username"];
        $member["password"] = $row["password"];
        $member["guild_id"] = $row["guild_id"];
        $member["guild_name"] = $row["guild_name"];
        $member["guild_code"] = $row["guild_code"];
        array_push($members["member" + (string)$x], $member);
        $x++;
    }
    array_push($response["members"], $members);

    echo json_encode($response);;
}
```

In JQuery this type of method works.. my question is, is there any way i can achieve it using php? If you know i will be very happy to know...

Comment: what you need is putting a member on a unique index.

Comment: yep and i am trying to use a string type of index..

Comment: @Siege21x  a much better solution given by me. check and try once

Comment: @AlivetoDie sure man. I'll make sure to try that out! Thanks alot!

Comment: Was able to have it man. I voted for your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Suggestion:-stop using deprecated+removed(php5 +php7) version of `mysql_*`.Move towards `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` along with `prepared statements`(Prevent Sql Injection)

2.Why creating unnecessary array and multiple push.No need to do that.Do like below:-

```
$response["members"] = array();//put outside
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $x = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $response["members"][$x]["member_id"] = $row["member_id"]; //assign value directly to the resultant array
        $response["members"][$x]["firstname"] = $row["firstname"];
        $response["members"][$x]["mi"] = $row["mi"];
        $response["members"][$x]["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];
        $response["members"][$x]["email"] = $row["email"];
        $response["members"][$x]["username"] = $row["username"];
        $response["members"][$x]["password"] = $row["password"];
        $response["members"][$x]["guild_id"] = $row["guild_id"];
        $response["members"][$x]["guild_name"] = $row["guild_name"];
        $response["members"][$x]["guild_code"] = $row["guild_code"];
        $x++;
    }
}

if(count($response["members"])>0){ //check finally that array is not empty
 echo json_encode($response); //echo json encoded array data
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the idea in this kind of saving the data within arrays. I'll read the difference between mysql and mysqli for me to understand what you are talking about :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to achieve that the `members` array contains individual records with keys as `member0`, `member1`, etc., then you could proceed as:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $x = 0;
    $members = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $member = array();
        $member["member_id"] = $row["member_id"];
        $member["firstname"] = $row["firstname"];
        $member["mi"] = $row["mi"];
        $member["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];
        $member["email"] = $row["email"];
        $member["username"] = $row["username"];
        $member["password"] = $row["password"];
        $member["guild_id"] = $row["guild_id"];
        $member["guild_name"] = $row["guild_name"];
        $member["guild_code"] = $row["guild_code"];
        $members["member$x"] = $member;
        $x++;
    }
    $response["members"] = $members;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll make sure to try this out and declare this the answer if it will work! Thanks! :D